# Best practice to return errors in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have concerns on the way that we returns errors to client.

Do we return error immediately by throwing [HttpResponseException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpresponseexception(v=vs.118).aspx) when we get an error:

```
public void Post(Customer customer)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.Name))
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException("Customer Name cannot be empty", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) 
    }
    if (customer.Accounts.Count == 0)
    {
         throw new HttpResponseException("Customer does not have any account", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) 
    }
}
```

Or we accumulate all errors then send back to client:

```
public void Post(Customer customer)
{
    List<string> errors = new List<string>();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.Name))
    {
        errors.Add("Customer Name cannot be empty"); 
    }
    if (customer.Accounts.Count == 0)
    {
         errors.Add("Customer does not have any account"); 
    }
    var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage<List<string>>(errors, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    throw new HttpResponseException(responseMessage);
}
```

This is just a sample code, it does not matter either validation errors or server error, I just would like to know the best practice, the pros and cons of each approach.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22163675/200442 you should be using `ModelState`.

Comment: Note that answers here only cover Exceptions that are thrown in the controller itself.  If your API returns an IQueryable<Model> that has not been executed yet, the exception is not in the controller and is not caught...

Comment: Very nice question but somehow I'm not getting any constructor overload of `HttpResponseException` class which takes two parameters mentioned in your post - `HttpResponseException("Customer Name cannot be empty", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)`  i.e. `HttpResponseException(string, HttpStatusCode)`

Answer (score 348, accepted):

For me I usually send back an `HttpResponseException` and set the status code accordingly depending on the exception thrown and if the exception is fatal or not will determine whether I send back the `HttpResponseException` immediately.

At the end of the day it's an API sending back responses and not views, so I think it's fine to send back a message with the exception and status code to the consumer. I currently haven't needed to accumulate errors and send them back as most exceptions are usually due to incorrect parameters or calls etc.

An example in my app is that sometimes the client will ask for data, but there isn't any data available so I throw a custom `NoDataAvailableException` and let it bubble to the Web API app, where then in my custom filter which captures it sending back a relevant message along with the correct status code.

I am not 100% sure on what's the best practice for this, but this is working for me currently so that's what I'm doing.

**Update**:

Since I answered this question a few blog posts have been written on the topic:

https://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/asp-net-web-api-exception-handling

(this one has some new features in the nightly builds)
https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/youssefm/error-handling-in-asp-net-webapi

**Update 2**

Update to our error handling process, we have two cases:

1. For general errors like not found, or invalid parameters being passed to an action we return a `HttpResponseException` to stop processing immediately. Additionally for model errors in our actions we will hand the model state dictionary to the `Request.CreateErrorResponse` extension and wrap it in a `HttpResponseException`. Adding the model state dictionary results in a list of the model errors sent in the response body.
2. For errors that occur in higher layers, server errors, we let the exception bubble to the Web API app, here we have a global exception filter which looks at the exception, logs it with ELMAH and tries to make sense of it setting the correct HTTP status code and a relevant friendly error message as the body again in a `HttpResponseException`. For exceptions that we aren't expecting the client will receive the default 500 internal server error, but a generic message due to security reasons.

**Update 3**

Recently, after picking up Web API 2, for sending back general errors we now use the [IHttpActionResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.ihttpactionresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) interface, specifically the built in classes for in the `System.Web.Http.Results` namespace such as NotFound, BadRequest when they fit, if they don't we extend them, for example a NotFound result with a response message:

```
public class NotFoundWithMessageResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private string message;

    public NotFoundWithMessageResult(string message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        response.Content = new StringContent(message);
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer geepie, it is a good experience, so you prefer to send expcetion immediately?

Comment: As i said it really depends on the exception. A fatal exception such as for example the user passes the Web Api an invalid parameter to an endpoint, then i would create a HttpResponseException and return it straight away to the consuming app.

Comment: The exceptions in the question are really more about validation see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22163675/200442.

Comment: @DanielLittle Reread his question. I quote: "This is just a sample code, it does not matter either validation errors or server error"

Comment: @gdp Even so there really are two components to it, validation and exceptions, so it's best to cover both.

Comment: Isn't it an `HttpResponseMessage` since `HttpResponse` expects an `System.IO.TextWriter`? `var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);`

Comment: So, [my question is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274989/) - I like how my generated AutoRest client deserializes my main entities when dealing with the 200 scenarios.. I wish I didn't have to manually parse the 400 scenarios

Comment: In .NET Core there is e.g. BadRequestObjectResult and NotFoundObjectResult which allow you to return results with objects / messages if that is the only customisation required (and you are returning one of the types that have ObjectResult varieties)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling

Answer (score 208):

ASP.NET Web API 2 really simplified it. For example, the following code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetProduct(int id)
{
    Product item = repository.Get(id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        var message = string.Format("Product with id = {0} not found", id);
        HttpError err = new HttpError(message);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, err);
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, item);
    }
}
```

returns the following content to the browser when the item is not found:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 09 Aug 2012 23:27:18 GMT
Content-Length: 51

{
  "Message": "Product with id = 12 not found"
}
```

Suggestion: Don't throw HTTP Error 500 unless there is a catastrophic error (for example, WCF Fault Exception). Pick an appropriate HTTP status code that represents the state of your data. (See the apigee link below.)

Links:

- [Exception Handling in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling) (asp.net)
  and
- [RESTful API Design: what about errors?](https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_what_about_errors) (apigee.com)

Comment: I would go one step further and throw a ResourceNotFoundException from the DAL/Repo which I check in the Web Api 2.2 ExceptionHandler for the Type ResourceNotFoundException and then I return "Product with id xxx not found". That way its generically anchored in the architecture instead of each action.

Comment: Is there any specific use for the `return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);`  What is the difference between `CreateResponse` and `CreateErrorResponse`

Comment: According to, http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html, a client error is a 400 level code and a server error is a 500 level code.  So a 500 error code might be very appropriate in many cases for a Web API, not just "catastrophic" errors.

Comment: You need `using System.Net.Http;` for the `CreateResponse()` extension method to show up.

Comment: What I don't like about using Request.CreateResponse() is that it returns unnecessary Microsoft-specific serialization info like "<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">My error here</string>".  For situations when 400 status is appropriate I found that ApiController.BadRequest(string message) returns a better "<Error><Message>My error here</Message></Error>" string.
But I cannot find its equivalent for returning 500 status with a simple message.

Comment: Actually, similar result for 500 might be achieved (see http://goo.gl/0qfD5D) by using

ResponseMessage(new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent("<Error><Message>My error message</Message></Error>", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError });

Comment: Then essentially return type of every method of my web API will be `HttpResponseMessage`. Is that ok? Whether I'm returning a string, json or a custom object. Whatever  be my final return thing I simply assign it to item property. Is that a correct understanding from my end?

Comment: How can I return a json result? Something like this:`return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Json(bonds));` like `JsonResult<GetBondsResponse>`

Comment: I agree.  I think we need to stop using Exceptions unless something, well, exceptional, has actually happened.  Just because you want to return an HTTP 500 to the client doesn't mean you need to use an exception for this, including the work that the run-time has to do to wrap, then unwrap that exception.  Just return the 500.  If I see something go through my applications general exception handler, I want that to be because something that I did not expect to happen, happened, NOT because the user tried to do something they weren't supposed to do (like call the API with no name).

Comment: While I agree that exceptions should not be thrown lightly, the current solution abstracts away the service return type from specifif repository item type to "it can return anything". I think exception would be the lesser evil.

Comment: [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status405MethodNotAllowed)] return NotFound(); return BadRequest() .  Task<IActionResult> allows you to use the controller to detect error conditions  and return NotFound or BadRequest to the client.  you can do all error condition logic in the controller

Comment: I don't like this. 404 means page not found or url resource wasn't found. The API endpoint WAS found so it's a 200.  The fact that there was no data shouldn't be a 404. There should be an empty data set and perhaps a message for the client. I'd use a 200. It's a web success but no data. If it was a file it could be a 404.

Answer (score 86):

It looks like you're having more trouble with Validation than errors/exceptions so I'll say a bit about both.

**Validation**

Controller actions should generally take Input Models where the validation is declared directly on the model.

```
public class Customer
{ 
    [Require]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use an `ActionFilter` that automatically sends validation messages back to the client.

```
public class ValidationActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var modelState = actionContext.ModelState;

        if (!modelState.IsValid) {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                 .CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, modelState);
        }
    }
}
```

For more information about this check out http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/automatic-modelstate-validation-in-aspnet-mvc

**Error handling**

It's best to return a message back to the client that represents the exception that happened (with relevant status code).

Out of the box you have to use `Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode, message)` if you want to specify a message. However, this ties the code to the `Request` object, which you shouldn't need to do.

I usually create my own type of "safe" exception that I expect the client would know how to handle and wrap all others with a generic 500 error.

Using an action filter to handle the exceptions would look like this:

```
public class ApiExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var exception = context.Exception as ApiException;
        if (exception != null) {
            context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(exception.StatusCode, exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can register it globally.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ApiExceptionFilterAttribute());
```

This is my custom exception type.

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace WebApi
{
    public class ApiException : Exception
    {
        private readonly HttpStatusCode statusCode;

        public ApiException (HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message, Exception ex)
            : base(message, ex)
        {
            this.statusCode = statusCode;
        }

        public ApiException (HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
            : base(message)
        {
            this.statusCode = statusCode;
        }

        public ApiException (HttpStatusCode statusCode)
        {
            this.statusCode = statusCode;
        }

        public HttpStatusCode StatusCode
        {
            get { return this.statusCode; }
        }
    }
}
```

An example exception that my API can throw.

```
public class NotAuthenticatedException : ApiException
{
    public NotAuthenticatedException()
        : base(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an issue related with the error handling answer at the ApiExceptionFilterAttribute  class definition. In the OnException method, the exception.StatusCode is not valid since exception is a WebException. What can I do in this case?

Comment: @razp26 if you're referring to the like `var exception = context.Exception as WebException;` that was a typo, it should have been `ApiException`

Comment: Can you please add an example of how the ApiExceptionFilterAttribute  class would be used?

Answer (score 40):

You can throw a HttpResponseException

```
HttpResponseMessage response = 
    this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "your message");
throw new HttpResponseException(response);
```

Comment: These classes/methods don't seem to be available in .net 5. Maybe BadHttpRequestException replaces these.

Answer (score 33):

If you are using ASP.NET Web API 2, the easiest way is to use the ApiController Short-Method. This will result in a BadRequestResult.

```
return BadRequest("message");
```

Comment: Strictly for model validation errors I use the overload of BadRequest() that accepts the ModelState object: `return BadRequest(ModelState);`

Answer (score 25):

For Web API 2 my methods consistently return IHttpActionResult so I use...

```
public IHttpActionResult Save(MyEntity entity)
{
    ....
    if (...errors....)
        return ResponseMessage(
            Request.CreateResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
                validationErrors));

    // otherwise success
    return Ok(returnData);
}
```

Comment: This answer is okay, while you should add reference to `System.Net.Http`

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to 2022! Now we have other answers in .NET (since ASP.NET Core 2.1). Look at this article: [Using the ProblemDetails Class in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://code-maze.com/using-the-problemdetails-class-in-asp-net-core-web-api/), where the author explains the following best practices:

1. How to implement standard [IETF RFC 7807](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7807), which defines a "problem detail" as a way to carry machine-readable details of errors in an HTTP response to avoid the need to define new error response formats for HTTP APIs.
2. How model validations use the [ProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails?view=aspnetcore-6.0) class to populate a list of validation errors - the direct answer to the question for a general rule, whether to break processing after the first error.

As a teaser, this is how the JSON output looks if we use `ProductDetails` and multiple errors:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use custom ActionFilter in Web Api to validate model:

```
public class DRFValidationFilters : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                .CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);

            //BadRequest(actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }

    public override Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                    .CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
            }
        });
    }

    public class AspirantModel
    {
        public int AspirantId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string AspirantType { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$",
            ErrorMessage = "Not a valid Phone number")]
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public int CenterId { get; set; }


        [HttpPost]
        [Route("AspirantCreate")]
        [DRFValidationFilters]
        public IHttpActionResult Create(AspirantModel aspirant)
        {
            if (aspirant != null)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                return Conflict();
            }

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Register CustomAttribute class in webApiConfig.cs
config.Filters.Add(new DRFValidationFilters());

Answer (score 4):

Building up upon `Manish Jain`'s answer (which is meant for Web API 2 which simplifies things):

1) Use **validation structures** to response as many validation errors as possible. These structures can also be used to response to requests coming from forms.

```
public class FieldError
{
    public String FieldName { get; set; }
    public String FieldMessage { get; set; }
}

// a result will be able to inform API client about some general error/information and details information (related to invalid parameter values etc.)
public class ValidationResult<T>
{
    public bool IsError { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// validation message. It is used as a success message if IsError is false, otherwise it is an error message
    /// </summary>
    public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public List<FieldError> FieldErrors { get; set; } = new List<FieldError>();

    public T Payload { get; set; }

    public void AddFieldError(string fieldName, string fieldMessage)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fieldName))
            throw new ArgumentException("Empty field name");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fieldMessage))
            throw new ArgumentException("Empty field message");

        // appending error to existing one, if field already contains a message
        var existingFieldError = FieldErrors.FirstOrDefault(e => e.FieldName.Equals(fieldName));
        if (existingFieldError == null)
            FieldErrors.Add(new FieldError {FieldName = fieldName, FieldMessage = fieldMessage});
        else
            existingFieldError.FieldMessage = $"{existingFieldError.FieldMessage}. {fieldMessage}";

        IsError = true;
    }

    public void AddEmptyFieldError(string fieldName, string contextInfo = null)
    {
        AddFieldError(fieldName, $"No value provided for field. Context info: {contextInfo}");
    }
}

public class ValidationResult : ValidationResult<object>
{

}
```

2) **Service layer** will return `ValidationResult`s, regardless of operation being successful or not. E.g:

```
    public ValidationResult DoSomeAction(RequestFilters filters)
    {
        var ret = new ValidationResult();

        if (filters.SomeProp1 == null) ret.AddEmptyFieldError(nameof(filters.SomeProp1));
        if (filters.SomeOtherProp2 == null) ret.AddFieldError(nameof(filters.SomeOtherProp2 ), $"Failed to parse {filters.SomeOtherProp2} into integer list");

        if (filters.MinProp == null) ret.AddEmptyFieldError(nameof(filters.MinProp));
        if (filters.MaxProp == null) ret.AddEmptyFieldError(nameof(filters.MaxProp));


        // validation affecting multiple input parameters
        if (filters.MinProp > filters.MaxProp)
        {
            ret.AddFieldError(nameof(filters.MinProp, "Min prop cannot be greater than max prop"));
            ret.AddFieldError(nameof(filters.MaxProp, "Check"));
        }

        // also specify a global error message, if we have at least one error
        if (ret.IsError)
        {
            ret.Message = "Failed to perform DoSomeAction";
            return ret;
        }

        ret.Message = "Successfully performed DoSomeAction";
        return ret;
    }
```

3) **API Controller** will construct the response based on service function result

One option is to put virtually all parameters as optional and perform custom validation which return a more meaningful response. Also, I am taking care not to allow any exception to go beyond the service boundary.

```
    [Route("DoSomeAction")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage DoSomeAction(int? someProp1 = null, string someOtherProp2 = null, int? minProp = null, int? maxProp = null)
    {
        try
        {
            var filters = new RequestFilters 
            {
                SomeProp1 = someProp1 ,
                SomeOtherProp2 = someOtherProp2.TrySplitIntegerList() ,
                MinProp = minProp, 
                MaxProp = maxProp
            };

            var result = theService.DoSomeAction(filters);
            return !result.IsError ? Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result) : Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, exc, "Failed to DoSomeAction");
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new HttpError("Failed to DoSomeAction - internal error"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the built in "InternalServerError" method (available in ApiController):

```
return InternalServerError();
//or...
return InternalServerError(new YourException("your message"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of these answers seem to be relics of the past.  I've found the solution below to be simple and work well.  This is in .NET 6 for a Web API [derived from `ControllerBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Rather than throwing exceptions, you can directly return the various HTTP response codes as objects, along with an exact error message:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[ApiController]
public class MyWebApiController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<int> Process(Customer customer)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.Name))
            return BadRequest("Customer Name cannot be empty");

        if (!Customers.Find(customer))
            return NotFound("Customer does not have an account");

        // After validating inputs, core logic goes here...

        return Ok(customer.ID);  // or simply "return Ok()" if not returning data
    }
}
```

See a list of error codes available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.badrequest?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

As for when to return the errors (OP's question), it depends on the requirement.  Returning errors as they happen means you avoid the overhead of additional processing, but then the client has to make repeated calls to get all the errors.  Consider the server viewpoint also, as it may cause undesirable program behavior to continue server-side processing when an error has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update on the current state of ASP.NET WebAPI. The interface is now called `IActionResult` and implementation hasn't changed much:

```
[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
public class DuplicateEntityException : IActionResult
{        
    public DuplicateEntityException(object duplicateEntity, object entityId)
    {
        this.EntityType = duplicateEntity.GetType().Name;
        this.EntityId = entityId;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Id of the duplicate (new) entity
    /// </summary>
    public object EntityId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Type of the duplicate (new) entity
    /// </summary>
    public string EntityType { get; set; }

    public Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        var message = new StringContent($"{this.EntityType ?? "Entity"} with id {this.EntityId ?? "(no id)"} already exist in the database");

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Ambiguous) { Content = message };

        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, but where specifically in the project is this code placed? I am doing my web api 2 project in vb.net.

Comment: It's just a model for returning the error and can reside anywhere.
You would return a new instance of the above class in your Controller.
But to be honest I try to use the built in classes whenever possible:
this.Ok(), CreatedAtRoute(), NotFound(). The signature of the method would be IHttpActionResult.
Don't know if they changed all this with NetCore

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> PostUser(int UserTypeId, User user)
{
  if (somethingFails)
  {
    // Return the error message like this.
    return new BadRequestObjectResult(new
    {
      message = "Something is not working here"
    });
  }

  return ok();
}
```

Comment: This is not for WebAPI, is for MVC...

Comment: This is directly copied from a web api repo @benjamingranados

Comment: If your source is https://www.likecs.com/ask-77378.html, is still not for WebApi, is just a "Try this" response on a forum. Maybe you can share the source link.

Comment: I'm giving you a upvote here, this worked fine and was what I was looking for on my webapi C# 6 implementation:  return BadRequest(new { message = "The service is not implemented as of yet." });

Comment: Seems like this link supports @Zablon https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-7.0#asynchronous-action-1

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to create a global exception handler. I'm using .Net 6 and I've tried most of the solutions listed here and none of them worked in my case. I think is because they are for asp.net (framework one).
Here is my solution that worked in .Net 6:

1. Create you custom exception filter class that implements IExceptionFilter (from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters namespace):

   ```
    public class CustomExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
    {
     private readonly ILogger<CustomExceptionFilter> _logger;
     public CustomExceptionFilter(ILogger<CustomExceptionFilter> logger)
      {
        _logger = logger;
      }
     public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
     {
       _logger.LogError(context.Exception.Message, context.Exception);
       HttpStatusCode status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
       string message = "Service is unavailable.";

       var result = new ObjectResult(new { error = message })
       {
         StatusCode = (int)status
       };

       context.Result = result;
       context.ExceptionHandled = true;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Decorate your controller or action method with this attribute:

   ```
   [ServiceFilter(typeof(CustomExceptionFilter))]
   ```
3. Register your filter inside AddController() method at Startup:

   ```
   services.AddControllers(options =>
   {
      options.Filters.Add<CustomExceptionFilter>();
   });
   ```

Happy coding!

Answer (score -2):

For those errors where modelstate.isvalid is false, I generally send the error as it is thrown by the code. Its easy to understand for the developer who is consuming my service. I generally send the result using below code.

```
     if(!ModelState.IsValid) {
                List<string> errorlist=new List<string>();
                foreach (var value in ModelState.Values)
                {
                    foreach(var error in value.Errors)
                    errorlist.Add( error.Exception.ToString());
                    //errorlist.Add(value.Errors);
                }
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,errorlist);}
```

This sends the error to the client in below format which is basically a list of errors:

```
    [  
    "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: **Could not convert string to integer: abc. Path 'Country',** line 6, position 16.\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsInt32Internal()\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsInt32()\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter, Boolean inArray)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)",

       "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: **Could not convert string to integer: ab. Path 'State'**, line 7, position 13.\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsInt32Internal()\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsInt32()\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter, Boolean inArray)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)"
    ]
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend sending back this level of detail in the exception if this was an external API (i.e. exposed to the public internet). You should do some more work in the filter and send back a JSON object (or XML if that's the chosen format) detailing the error rather than just a ToString of exception.

Comment: Correct dont sent this exception for external API. But you can use it to debug issues in internal API and during testing.