# IHttpActionResult - How to use?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I've seen examples of using some of the new IHttpActionResults for OK, NotFound. 
I haven't seen anything using `Unauthorized()`.

my existing code looks like:

```
catch (SecurityException ex)
{
    request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, ex.Message);
}
```

I'd like to replace it with this:

```
catch (SecurityException ex)
{
    response = Unauthorized();
}
```

but I don't see any overload to pass exception details.

Also, what is the `IHttpActionResult` equivalent of returning a 500 error?

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    response = request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, 
                                           ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: I found                 response = InternalServerError(ex);
to address the 500 issue.. I'm still looking for an example of Unauthorized that accepts a string message.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per the code for [ApiController](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/ApiController.cs), there are only two overloads for `Unauthorized()`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates an <see cref="UnauthorizedResult"/> (401 Unauthorized) with the specified values.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="challenges">The WWW-Authenticate challenges.</param>
/// <returns>An <see cref="UnauthorizedResult"/> with the specified values.</returns>
protected internal UnauthorizedResult Unauthorized(params AuthenticationHeaderValue[] challenges)
{
    return Unauthorized((IEnumerable<AuthenticationHeaderValue>)challenges);
}

/// <summary>
/// Creates an <see cref="UnauthorizedResult"/> (401 Unauthorized) with the specified values.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="challenges">The WWW-Authenticate challenges.</param>
/// <returns>An <see cref="UnauthorizedResult"/> with the specified values.</returns>
protected internal virtual UnauthorizedResult Unauthorized(IEnumerable<AuthenticationHeaderValue> challenges)
{
    return new UnauthorizedResult(challenges, this);
}
```

So it looks like you are out of luck, unless you want to make the change yourself (fork your own version of WebAPI or do a pull request to attempt to get it into the main branch).

---

The `IHttpActionResult` equivalent of returning a 500 error is this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates an <see cref="ExceptionResult"/> (500 Internal Server Error) with the specified exception.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="exception">The exception to include in the error.</param>
/// <returns>An <see cref="ExceptionResult"/> with the specified exception.</returns>
protected internal virtual ExceptionResult InternalServerError(Exception exception)
{
    return new ExceptionResult(exception, this);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can read more about Unathorized() here 
[How do you return status 401 from WebAPI to AngularJS and also include a custom message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025884/how-do-you-return-status-401-from-webapi-to-angularjs-and-also-include-a-custom)
If found another way - without throwing an exception and using HttpResponseMessage as return type of your controller , you can do it like this:

```
return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "I am unauthorized IHttpActionResult custom message!"));
```

More about ResponseMessage() here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.responsemessage%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution for a 500 exception with custom message (expanded on from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10734690/654708)

Base class for all Web API controllers

```
public abstract class ApiBaseController : ApiController
{
    protected internal virtual IHttpActionResult InternalServerError(Exception ex, string message = null)
    {
        var customMsg = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message) ? "" : String.Format("Custom error message : {0}. ", message);
        var errorMsg = String.Format("{0}{1}", customMsg, ex);
        return new InternalServerErrorWithMessageResult(errorMsg);
    }
}

public class InternalServerErrorWithMessageResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly string message;

    public InternalServerErrorWithMessageResult(string message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                       {
                           Content = new StringContent(message)
                       };
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

Sample Web API controllers

```
public class ProductController : ApiBaseController
{
    public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var product = productService.GetProduct(id);
            return Ok(product); // 200 w/ product
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
           //return InternalServerError(ex); // Uses default InternalServerError
           return InternalServerError(ex, "My custom message here"); // Uses custom InternalServerError
        }
    }    

}
```