# How do you return status 401 from WebAPI to AngularJS and also include a custom message?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In my WebAPI class, an `ApiController`, I make a call such as:

```
string myCustomMessage = .....;

throw new HttpResponseException(
    new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        { ReasonPhrase = myCustomMessage });
```

When I call using AngularJS `$resource` service, I do get 401 in the status field the response, in the catch block of the promise.   The 401 matches `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized`, so all's well.

The problem, however, is that the data field of the response is empty (null).   I don't get the myCustomMessage returned.

Now, if rather than throwing a `HttpResponseException` exception, I just throw a regular `Exception` with a message, that message does make it sway back to Angular.

I need to be able to do both: return a custom message from the server, as well as have the returned status code be whatever I want, in this case 401.

Anyone know how to make that work?

[edit]
**Solution:**

```
 throw new HttpResponseException(
     Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, myCustomMessage));
```

Comment: What happens if you use plain `$http`?

Comment: Karolis, I am okay with using plain $http.  I would do that if we've determined that $resource cannot be used to solve this problem.  Has that been confirmed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try returning `HttpResponseMessage` like this.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(
              HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "You are not authorized");
}
```

This should produce an HTTP response message like this.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Date: Sat, 12 Apr 2014 07:12:54 GMT
Content-Length: 36

{"Message":"You are not authorized"}
```

Comment: I need a solution where I can throw the `HttpResponseException` exception.  Your proposal to use `Request.CreateErrorResponse` gets me there.

Looks like the code I before: `throw new HttpResponseException( new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) { ReasonPhrase = mymessage });`

When rewritten with `CreateErrorRespons` solves the problem: `throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, mymessage));`

Comment: this won't work on web api 2 btw since IHttpAcionResult is the new best pracice.

Answer (score 0):

I use a response interceptor for that.
A response interceptor is pretty much a "filter" where all responses pass through and I can ask about there status code and perform logic.

Something like this:

```
myModule.factory('responseInterceptor', function ($q) {
    return {
        response: function (res) {
           switch(res.status){
             case 401:
                     // do what you want
           }
           return res;
        },
        responseError: function (res) {
            return $q.reject(res);
        }
    };
});

myModule.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('responseInterceptor');
});
```

About your custom message, you can add it in a http header.
In my case, when I get a 401, I add a location header with a url and redirect to it.