# How do I return a statusCode to the client from a web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, http-response-codes

I am coding a `C#` webservice using `Web API 2` and I would like to be able to send a `StatusCode` of `Unauthorized` to the client if the client is not authorized with the correct credentials.

Here is the `ApiController` filter code:

```
public class ApiAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
            httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            actionContext.Response = httpResponseMessage;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `HttpClient` code:

```
private async Task<bool> RequestAuthorizeAsync(string serverAddress)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, serverAddress))
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = null;
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the `IsAuthorized` function returns `false`, with the `httpResponseMessage` object set, the `HttpClient` is still returning a `StatusCode` of 200, and not the `StatusCode` of 401.

Can I please have some help with returning a `StatusCode` of 401 to the `HttpClient`?

Comment: As an aside, your if/else in the client code can be change to just `return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
                    return response;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(
     Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, myCustomMessage));
                }
```

Possible duplicate:
[How do you return status 401 from WebAPI to AngularJS and also include a custom message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025884/how-do-you-return-status-401-from-webapi-to-angularjs-and-also-include-a-custom)

Answer (score 0):

Check out .Net's [JsonResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn337124(v=vs.118).aspx)

Then you can just return a `Task<IHttpActionResult>` like so...

```
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
```