# .NET throw exception with JSON content type

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a web API project that uses the .NET MVC 4 framework. My API is focused around returning JOSN objects, and works perfectly except for when I want to return exceptions in a JSON format.

The code I have below is what I am using to try and force a JSON return, but the response generated from this code is the default HTML content type. I'm looking for a way to return an exception using the "application/json" content type. Any suggestions?

```
public static void ThrowHttpException(HttpStatusCode code, string content)
{
    string message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { message = content });
    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(code)
    {
        Content = new StringContent(message),
        ReasonPhrase = null
    };
    throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
}
```

Comment: `throw new HttpResponseException(resp);` are you catching this exception?

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning an [HttpStatusCodeResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416534(v=vs.118).aspx) in the first place?

Comment: This thing doesn't look like action at all. It throws exception rather than returning ActionResult

Comment: This is a function that is called when an exception is caught within an ApiController.

Comment: The point of this is to be called when an exception is thrown.

Comment: Have you looked at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732644/best-practice-to-return-errors-in-asp-net-web-api?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably create action like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult ThrowHttpException(HttpStatusCode code, string content)
{
    string message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { message = content });
    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(code)
    {
        Content = new StringContent(message),
        ReasonPhrase = null
    };
    return resp;
}
```

Instead of throwin an exception you should return from the action the response object.