# How to throw Business Exception from Web API via HTTP Client

Tags: c#

I have below exception contract.

```
public class AdminBusinessException : Exception
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Exception Code.
    /// </summary>
    public string ExceptionCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Description.
    /// </summary>
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initiates here.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exceptionCode"></param>
    /// <param name="description"></param>
    public AdminBusinessException(string exceptionCode, string   description)
    {
        this.ExceptionCode = exceptionCode;
        this.Description = description;
    }
 }
```

So i want to throw **exception code** as well as **description** to my Http Client.
Any one please help me on this.

I am strucking on this :( :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web API throw custom exception back to client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718868/web-api-throw-custom-exception-back-to-client)

Answer (score 0):

Your Web APIs should handle the response using the HTTP conventions and you can include a message in the body.

ex:

```
Public IHttpActionResult DoSomethingBusiness(int id)
{
    if(some error from client)
      return BadRequest("some error message here")

     return Ok("Everything seems good")
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to throw exception object to client?

Comment: An exception object means a server error, in this case you have to return a status code like 500, and include an error message that inidcates what happened.

If the error was due to an issue in the client data, then you have to return (Bad Request) and also include the exception details in the message body, something like this;

        return BadRequest(exception.ToString())