# Unable to return type Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document from web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure Document DB and can successfully create an object using the code below. However I am not able to return the created object back to the client. Despite the code hitting the line return Ok(doc); the response seen in both Fiddler and Postman is always empty.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateNewApplication(dynamic data)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("data was empty");
        }

        try
        {
            var doc = _applicationResource.Save(data);
            return Ok(doc);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Resource

```
 public async Task<Document> Save(dynamic application)
    {
        Document created;

        using (Client)
        {
            application.id = Guid.NewGuid();
            var database = await RetrieveOrCreateDatabaseAsync(Database);
            var collection = await RetrieveOrCreateCollectionAsync(database.SelfLink, CollectionName);

            //persist the documents in DocumentDB
            created = await Client.CreateDocumentAsync(collection.SelfLink, application);

        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Application saved with ID {0} resourceId {1}", created.Id, created.ResourceId);

        return created;

    }
```

Note I'm new to using async / await. I thought that the return value should be the type of the task i.e. Task. That said I have tried returning both to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you `await` for a function that returns a `Task<T>`, you get a value of type `T`. That's why you put the `await` word in front of the function call.

Second, what makes Web API very easy to use is that you don't need to work on the HTTP protocol level and return an `IHttpActionResult` created by hand: you should return directly the value that you want, without "wrapping" it in any HTTP artifact.

If your action method can return different kind of values, declare the return type as `object`. But usually you will always return an object of the same type, `Document` in your case, and, in case of error, instead of returning a  value of other kind, you can throw an `HttpResponseException`. See this fro more info: [Best practice to return errors in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732644/best-practice-to-return-errors-in-asp-net-web-api)