# Should I try to take BadRequest(ModelState) returned from my API, and deserialize to *what* with JSON.NET?

Tags: json.net, asp.net-web-api2, autorest

**TL;DR;**

"I like how my generated AutoRest client deserializes my main entities when dealing with the 200 scenarios.. but, MUST I manually parse the 400 scenarios?", said the lazy programmer

**DETAILS:**

So, I have an API, (Web API 2), and I do all the standard stuff.. using POCO's that implement `IValidatable` in addition to property-level validation using `System.Data.DataAnnotations` my Web API returns 400 errors like this (just an example):

```
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
```

And, where appropriate I use `SwaggerResponse` attributes, and my swagger.json is documented thus so that my generated client knows that a 400 is a viable response.

Now, my unit tests which directly instantiate the api controllers, I purposely try to test for invalid model state.. I can take the  `IHttpActionResult` response from the controller invocation, and cast it to `InvalidModelStateResult` and iterate over the ModelState dictionary.

[image]

But, I find writing something similar for my 'production HTTP calls' with an actual HTTP client -- not as straightforward.

So, getting closer to the heart of my question:

**Is there a preferred method for deserializing the `InvalidModelStateResult`?**

So, when interacting with my API with actual http calls.. via the `Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient` the JSON that I get back is in a slightly different shape..

*Example MVC controller code interacting with my API:*

```
HttpOperationResponse resp = await client.SpecialLocations.PatchByIdWithHttpMessagesAsync(id, locationType, "return=representation");

if (!resp.Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    //The JSON returned here is not really in the form of an InvalidModelStateResult
    ViewBag.Error = await resp.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return View(locationType);
}
```

[image: example of JSON when a 400 response is recieved]

Answer (score 0):

So, for now, I'm using Newtonsoft's `JObject` to parse `ModelState` returned from my WebAPI (again - it's not really named as such once retrieved via http request) and now pushing it into my MVC controller's `ModelState`.

This is my answer for now. But will consider others that have any merit. It just seems like a weird thing to have to do.

```
HttpOperationResponse resp = await client.SpecialLocations.PatchByIdWithHttpMessagesAsync(id, locationType, "return=representation");

if (resp.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
{
  string jsonErrStr = await resp.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  JObject err = JObject.Parse(jsonErrStr);
  string[] valPair = ((string)err["error"]["innererror"]["message"]).Split(":".ToCharArray());

  //now push into MVC controller's modelstate, so jQuery validation can show it
  this.ModelState.AddModelError(valPair[0].Trim(),valPair[1].Trim());
  return View(locationType);
}
```