# HttpResponseMessage ignoring content when status code is not 200

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working with `ASP.Net MVC 5` and `Web Api 2 Controller` and I'm facing a really annoying thing.

When I send an `HttpResponseMessage` using, for example, a `400` status code, I would like to send a `string` message with the reason.

If I return an `HTTP 200` the content is displayed correctly, but if I do something like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response.Content = new StringContent("This is a bad request man.");
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/text");
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
return response;
```

It doesn't seem to work.

Is this a bad practice? Am I wrong when I think that I should return a message in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Repeated question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732644/best-practice-to-return-errors-in-asp-net-web-api

Comment: I believe it's not repeated. Maybe the part on the best practices is, but I'd like to know why the thing I wrote doesn't work