# How to avoid Frmework version in IIS error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]

In below picture how to avoid showing of framework versions in default error message by IIS?

Comment: You should provide your own custom error pages and suppress all the of the ASP.NET generated error pages.  There are several options for this.  Look for "custom error ASP.NET" with your favorite search too.

Comment: it's an api. I can not show any pages. do i need to show some custom error response?

Comment: @NareshGarlapati yes create a custom response

Comment: Catch exceptions (either locally or with a registered handler) and return something (whatever makes sense in your API) to the caller with an HTTP status of 500.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (\*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: Note that you should also update the iis config to remove the headers like X_PoweredBy (something like that) which says it's coming from dotnet

Comment: Other reason to return custom response - right now someone is calling your API expecting xml or json, and they're getting an html page instead.  Causes all kinds of client parsing issues

Answer (score 0):

> In below picture how to avoid showing of framework versions in default error message by IIS?

As far as I know, if you set the custom error's mode attribute to On or remoteonly in the web.config. It will hide the details information for the error message and framework versions in default error message by IIS like below:

[image]

There is no need to hide the framework versions when you debug the whole application in the server, since customer will not see the details error message.

> yes create a custom response

If you want to create a custom error handler for asp.net web api, I suggest you could try to create a class inherits ExceptionFilterAttribute and overried the OnException method.

More details, you could refer to below answer's error handling part.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22163675/7609093